# When I don't select a RadioButton a MessageBox should show

Tags: vb.net

[image]

```
If rad0.Checked = False AndAlso rad1.Checked = False AndAlso rad12mmtongue.Checked = False AndAlso
   rad16mmtongue.Checked = False AndAlso rad2.Checked = False AndAlso rad2bytimber.Checked = False AndAlso
   rad3bytimber.Checked = False AndAlso rad5by7.Checked = False AndAlso rad5by8.Checked = False AndAlso
   rad8by10.Checked = False AndAlso rad8by12.Checked = False AndAlso radapex.Checked = False AndAlso
   raddeliveryandinstall.Checked = False AndAlso raddeliveryonly.Checked = False AndAlso radmetal.Checked = False AndAlso
   radnodelivery.Checked = False AndAlso radnone.Checked = False AndAlso radpent.Checked = False Then

        MessageBox.Show("Some items where Not selected ,Click ok To restart", "FORM NOT COMPLETED ", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        lstdisplay.Items.Clear()
        Application.Restart()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: when I don't select one radio button or  some of the radio buttons  the programme  should not run it should restart the application

Comment: Normally radio buttons only allow one selection unless they are in separate containers. It seems rather extreme to restart the application. Can't you just give the user another chance to select an option? How are you determining which selection the user makes?

Comment: @monicaafun I still don't see a question. You describe what your program should do, but not what it actually does. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would tend to do something like this: `If parentControl.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().All(Function(rb) Not rb.Checked) Then`.  In that case, `parentControl` is the control that contains the `RadioButtons`, e.g. the form or a `Panel`.

Comment: @MatSnow the programme must allow users to select every radio button but if a user don't select some or one of the radio button a message box should pop up asking the user to go and select the one he/she didn't select

Comment: @Mary when I use an error message without restart when the user clicks on the okay the application still run

Answer (score 0):

To check if neither button is checked:

```
If Not (rad0.Checked AndAlso rad1.Checked) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Write your Error Message")
End If
```

Comment: when I use this method even if all radio button is checked it still gives me an error message